# How to style <td> items inside <table> tag?

Tags: html, css

I am using jsp with css for style the `<td>` inside `<table>` tag.
I want the code like below:

[image]

But now I am getting :

[image]

```css
#bengalistorycontainer{
 width:100%;
 
}
table.my-special-table {
  width: 10px;
height: 10px; 

border: 1px rgb(89,89,89) solid;

}
```

```html
 
  <table class="my-special-table">
<tr>
            <c:forEach begin="1" end="${classfile}" var="i"varStatus="loop">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${classfile eq i}">
                        <td>${1}   </div></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <td><a href="#">${2}</a></td>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
        
   <c:if test="${totalpagenumber != 1}">
     <td>  <a href="#">next</a> </td>
    </c:if>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsvq4tso/1/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "table.my-special-table" must be "table.my-special-table td"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just edit your code to the following:

```css
#bengalistorycontainer{
  width:100%;
}
table.my-special-table td{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px; 
  border: 1px rgb(89,89,89) solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-special-table">
   <tr>
       <c:forEach begin="1" end="${classfile}" var="i"varStatus="loop">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${classfile eq i}">
                        <td>${1}   </div></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <td><a href="#">${2}</a></td>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
        
   <c:if test="${totalpagenumber != 1}">
     <td>  <a href="#">next</a> </td>
    </c:if>
```

you did select the table, not the td element.. :)